# postgresql: LIMIT for each IN clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT children.*
FROM
children
JOIN parents ON (children.parent_id = parents.id)
WHERE
parents.id IN (1,2,3,4,5)
ORDER BY children.age DESC
LIMIT 1
```

This will limit the result to 1 for the whole query. Instead, I want 1 child to be returned for each parent under `parents.id IN (1,2,3,4,5)` so I would like the query to return 5.

In other words, Each parent has multiple children and I want to return the one oldest child per parent

Is there anyway that this could be done?

Comment: If you have multiple children which has to be returned? Or is it random?

Comment: What datatype is `parents.id`? You shouldn't compare apples to oranges. `'1'` is a string value but `1` is a number. If `id` is defined as an integer, you should compare it to numbers, not strings.

Comment: fixed. it is a mock sql query so made a mistake

Comment: Each parent has multiple children and I want to return one child per parent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your sample query, the parent table isn't needed at all (because you don't need any columns from it).

The following should do it:

```
select id,
       parent_id,
       age,
       ... other columns ...
from (
  select id, 
         parent_id,
         age,
         ... other columns ...,
         row_number() over (partition by parent_id order by age) as rn
  from children
  where parent_id in (1,2,3,4,5)
) as ch
where rn = 1
order by age;
```

By changing the `order by` clause inside the window function you can control *which* child is returned if there is more than one. In this case I'm picking the youngest (`order by age`)

It seems you are new to SQL, so in order to understand the use of the window function (`row_number() over (...)`) you might want to run the inner select on its own and see what happens.

If you simplified your real statement and you indeed need columns from the table `parents` you could join the inner query with the `parents` table:

```
select p.*, -- all columns from the parents table
       ch.* -- all columns from the children table
from parents p 
  join (
      select id, 
             parent_id,
             age,
             ... other columns ...,
             row_number() over (partition by parent_id order by age) as rn
      from children
  ) as ch on ch.parent_id = p.id and ch.rn = 1
where p.id in (1,2,3,4,5)
order by ch.age;
```

The same effect can be achieved using Postgres' `distinct on` operator which might actually be faster.

Comment: Thank you for the details response. I was wondering would this type of queries by very slow? What if each parent had thousands of children and we need 50 children per parent?

Comment: @alumns Should work OK provided the table is properly indexed. `distinct on` is usually a bit faster, but not by magnitudes. But the only way to find out is to test it and check the execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try a different approach?

```
SELECT min(children.parent_id),parent_id,min(child),max(children.age)
FROM
parents left join children 
on parents.id=children.parent_id
WHERE
parents.id IN ('1','2','3','4','5')
group by parent_id
```

As said it depends which is the single child you want to extract.

Comment: Hey Fabrizo, Could you please help me understand how your query works. I am a little confused by min(children.parent_id),parent_id,min(child)

Comment: I editted my question with slightly different requirements now

Comment: Your use of `group by` does fulfill the requirement that only one child per parent is returned, but the age that is returned does not necessarily belong to that child.